# How to quickly invert a power function in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have a series of functional dependencies which look something like this.

y = 0.1222*x**0.8628

I would like to use sympy to get out x as a function of y.
Searching the internet I saw that `solve` can be used for that.
So I tried

```
x = Symbol('x', real=True, positive=True)
y = Symbol('y', real=True, positive=True)

solve(y - 0.1222*x**0.8628, x)
```

However, this doesn't work, because after 20 minutes the kernel is still busy.
I noted, that if I exchange with 0.8628 to a simpler power, like 0.8 or even 0.86 then the computation works quite quickly.

I would like some help on speeding this up, or maybe there is a much better approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that Sympy treats 0.8628 as a rational number (2157/2500) and tries to find **all** solutions of the algebraic equation y = 0.1222*x**(2157/2500),  before filtering them down to real and positive ones. Unfortunately, there are 2157 roots of this equation in the complex plane, and they are extremely ugly. So this takes a long time. With simpler fractions, like 0.8 = 4/5 or 0.86 = 43/50, it's not as bad (although I see slowdown with 0.86 already).

As asmeurer pointed out, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8515) and the solution is to set the flag rational=False

```
solve(y - 0.1222*x**0.8628, x, rational=False)
```

The output is `[11.4314187062073*y**1.15901715345387]`, returned quickly.

---

Another workaround I found is to introduce logarithms, which force Sympy to abandon the algebraic approach to the equation.

```
solve(log(y) - log(0.1222*x**0.8628), x)
```

returns `[11.4314187062073*y**(2500/2157)]` immediately. Interestingly, this approach maintains the exponent as a rational.

Comment: This works, thank you! Clearly some optimization needed here on Sympy's side.

Comment: You can prevent solve from converting to rationals using `solve(y - 0.1222*x**0.8628, x, rational=False)`.

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8515) in the SymPy issue tracker to change this default.

Comment: @asmeurer   Thanks, I added this information. I also found it curious that taking logarithms speeds up the calculation while _retaining_ the exponent as a rational number.

Comment: Keeping the exponent as rational should probably be considered a bug (I just tested in the development version of SymPy and the log version gives "maximum recursion depth exceeded", so there may be new bugs here).